# How to skip over white spaces in a string while reading from a file

Tags: c, file-io

I want to read 20 strings from a file which may or may not contain white spaces.Those strings are in consecutive lines in a file. I want to create a character array from a line which will not contain white spaces. How to do that?

eg:

```
aaa bbbbccc 
abcedefghij
```

and so on.

I want to create a char array which will have these elements, `{a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c}`
another array with `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}`

Can I use `sscanf`?

Comment: So you want to put every character into an array, but skip white spaces?

Comment: aaa bbbbccc is in one line and abcdefghij is in next line.

Comment: yes i want to skip white spaces and put the characters from a line in a character array.which function to use?

Comment: i have tried using sscanf but it stops scanning once it sees white space and neglect all the other characters after space.

Comment: "create a character array from a line" implies paying attention to the `\n`, which is a whitespace.  Looks like you want to "skip over white spaces" except for the `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char elements[10];
    char other[10];
    char *p = elements;
    char ch;
    int count = 0;

    fp=fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while(1==fscanf(fp, " %c", &ch)){
        p[count++] = ch;
        if(count == 10){
            p = other;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    {//check
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i<10; ++i){
            printf("%c", elements[i]);
            putchar(i < 9 ? ',' : '\n');
        }
        for(i = 0; i<10; ++i){
            printf("%c", other[i]);
            putchar(i < 9 ? ',' : '\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (probably not the fasted) way would be to read character wise using [`fgetc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html).

After having read a character, inspect it and skip each type of character you do not want.

To detect all kind of white-spaces use [`isspace()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html), to detect blanks only use [`isblank()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html).

Start copying the characters you want to a new allocated `char`-array ("string") for each fresh line read.

Comment: I don't think this is (much) slower than single `fgetc` calls, as both are sure to use the same standard file buffers. But "faster ∝ more difficult"; in this case, juggling only one character at a time is easy to grasp.

Comment: Umm yeah -- mixxed up 2 eerily similar posts :) But you seemed to get the underlying meaning anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there is a line break between "bbbbccc" and "abcedefghij", or how else would you know where to divide between the two char arrays?

Then I see two basic options that you have.

1) Read char by char, using getchar(). Skip whitespace, start a new string when you hit '\n'.
2) Use fgets(), reading a line a piece. Copy those strings into another string manually, skipping whitespace in the process.

Option 1) has the advantage that you only go through the data once.

Comment: yes theres a line break there. how to skip whitespace using fgets?

Comment: fgest reads all, say into a string called source. After that you say `while(*source) if( !isspace(*source++)) { *target++ = *(source-1); }

Comment: You _can_, but you don't _need_ to. You can also do what I wrote, which seems easier to me: Because with subsequent sscanf from lines with unknown numbers of whitespace-separated strings you'd need to keep track of the string position which is kindof messy. Is my example unclear? isspace() is a standard C library function whose declaration is found in ctype.h.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html).

To answer your question: yes, you can use `sscanf()` after `fgets()`!
But i'd walk through the whole input char-by-char and build a new string without spaces.

Comment: yes i used fgets as it will scan the lines but using sscanf my array will not consist of the characters after space..it neglects them.. what modifications to do?

Comment: as you have suggested which function should i use to scan char by char?

Comment: No function, access the array elements directly. After thinking about this for a moment I think `sscanf()` is not a useful tool for the job.

Comment: i want to make char array by reading a line which may or may not have whitespaces. i am not able to make out how to skip those whitespaces if at all there are in a line.